# How can I "click" download button on selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-crawlers

I want to download user data on Google analytics by using crawler so I write some code using selenium. However, I cannot click the "export" button. It always shows the error "no such element". I tried to use find_element_by_xpath, by_name and by_id.
I upload inspect of GA page below.

**I TRIED:**

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='download-link']").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ID-activity-userActivityTable"]/div/div[2]/span[6]/button')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class='_GAD.W_DECORATE_ELEMENT.C_USER_ACTIVITY_TABLE_CONTROL_ITEM_DOWNLOAD']')
```

**Python Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/parkjunhong/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
usrid = '1021'
url = 'https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/report/app-visitors-user-activity/a113876882w169675624p197020837/_u.date00=20190703&_u.date01=20190906&_r.userId='+usrid+'&_r.userListReportStates=%3F_u.date00=20190703%2526_u.date01=20190906%2526explorer- 
table.plotKeys=%5B%5D%2526explorer-table.rowStart=0%2526explorer- 
table.rowCount=1000&_r.userListReportId=app-visitors-user-id'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_name('identifier').send_keys('ID')
idlogin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/span/span')
idlogin.click()

driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('PASSWD')
element = driver.find_element_by_id('passwordNext')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
#login
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='download-link']").click()
#click the download button
```

**ERROR:**

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

[inspection of GA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np6u4.jpg)

Comment: Hi Can you Please Share Your website Link?

Comment: Or Can You Please Give Me Full inspect picture so i can check

Comment: @HamzaLachi I really appreciate your attention. I upload more inspect picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your click element is in an iFrame (iFrame id="galaxyIframe" ...). Therefore, you need to tell the driver to switch from the "main" page to said iFrame. If you add this line of code after your `#login` it should work:
`driver.switch_to.frame(galaxyIframe)`

(If the frame did not have a name, you would use: `iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath-to-frame")` and then `driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)`

To get back to your default frame, use:
`driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Crawling GA is generally a pain. Not just because you have these iFrames everywhere. 
Apart from that, I would recommend looking into [puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/), the new kid on the crawler block. Even though the prospect of switching to javascript from python may be daunting, it is worth it! Once you get into it, selenium will have felt super clunky.

Comment: Im really appreciate for your help. It is work! I really spend a lot of time into this problem. Again, really thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the text:

If you want to click on `'Export'-`

```
//button[contains(text(),'Export')]
```

Comment: I already tried but it still show same error... thanks for reply

Comment: yeah sure, please go ahead, the time i replied the dom was partial.